# Infinite sum with rational base raised to quadratic power

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for a closed form for sums (if it exists) of the type
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 x\right)^{an^2+bn+c}=\frac 1 {x^c} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 x\right)^{n(an+b)}
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{N}$ ($x\not= 1$) and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$. I think this should converge, due to $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 x\right)^{n(an+b)}< \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 x\right)^{bn}=\frac 1 {x^b-1}
$$
so that shouldn't be an issue. Any help/hints appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure these particular sums are studied much, but if you take the summation to be $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ rather than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ then these may be expressed in terms of theta functions. In particular, the Jacobi theta function is defined for complex $z,\tau$ as $\displaystyle \vartheta(z;\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}\eta^n$ where $q=e^{2\pi i z}$, $\eta=e^{\pi i \tau}$. So the sum over all integer $n$, not just positive $n$, is more familiar mathematically.

Comment: @Semiclassical thank you. so in this case we could set $q=x^{-a},\eta=x^{-b}$ and we'd obtain the desired summand, just missing the precise desired limits. in any case i'll need to read up on the Jacobi theta function!